# Regular expressions

Tags: context-free-grammar, bnf, regular-language, formal-languages

First of all I do not know if this is the correct translation for what I am asking.

In one of my courses we just stared learning about regular expressions, formal languages and so on.

```
Alphabet {1,0,S,R}
Terminals {1,0}
Rules:

S ::= 0
S ::= 1
S ::= 1R
R ::= 1R
R ::= 0R
R ::= 1
R ::= 0
```

In this case let say that I start with the 1R, then I could keep on going with either 1R or 0R.

If I start with 1R, then just a 1....then the sentence(in this case its binary numbers) is complete right? Because I can't "append" something afterwards, say 1R then I choose 1 and then I choose 1R again?

Thanks in advance, and please retag/move post if its uncorrect.

---

**ADDED:**

```
0  at rule S ::= 0  
1  with S ::= 1  
10 with S ::= 1R, so R ::= 0
```

How to generate 1100110?

This is not homework, it is an example/question from the powerpoint. I do not get how that is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a regular language, defined using a context free grammar. A regular expression that defines the same language is `(0)U(1{0,1}*)`. In plain english, the regular language contains all strings of 0s and 1s that start with 1, and the string 0.

A context free grammar starts with some initial non-terminal symbol, in this case it appears to be S. You then can replace any non-terminal symbols with a string of symbols according to the production rules listed. It is "done" when the string contains no non-terminal symbols.

In your example, you can only "choose 1R" if there is currently an S or an R in the string to replace. As it happens with this grammar, the first time you replace R with 1, you no longer have any non-terminals to replace, and that production of a string is finished.

Edit: Here is a trace of the production of 1100110.

```
S  
1R         via S ::= 1R
11R        via R ::= 1R
110R       via R ::= 0R
1100R      via R ::= 0R
11001R     via R ::= 1R
110011R    via R ::= 1R
1100110    via R ::= 0
```

Comment: I dont understand where you get R ::= 0R, I only see S ::= 0, S ::= 1, S ::= 1R and R ::= 0

Comment: @AndreasJohannessen: The 5th rule listed in your question is `R ::= 0R`. This rule allows me to replace an `R` with `0R`. Using this rule, I can turn `11R` into `110R`.

Comment: @Null set: No, look under the Added section, it is two different "grammatics"

Comment: @AndreasJohannessen: I think you must be mistaken. There is no new grammar listed in the Added section. It looks like that is a few examples of strings you can produce using the first grammar. If we were to assume that the rules listed in those examples were the only rules in a new grammar, then it would not be possible to make `1100110` in that grammar.

Comment: @Null set: 0  at rule S ::= 0  
1  with S ::= 1  
10 with S ::= 1R, so R ::= 0.......So this is not a new set of "rules" just an example then?

Comment: @AndreasJohannessen: Correct. It is showing how you can make the string `0` using rule 1, string `1` using rule 2, and string `10` using rule 3 followed by rule 7.

Comment: @Null set: Thank you for your time, then it all make sence!

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Appending is not allowed, only substitution. However with this language, you could continually make your string longer by choosing "R ::= 1R" or "R ::= 0R", and then substituting for R once again.

Answer (score 1):

> If I start with 1R, then just a 1....then the sentence(in this case its binary numbers) is complete right?

Yes, this is correct. The sentence 11 matches S = 1R = 11.

However with this grammar you could always use R = 1R or R= 0R to add more and more digits to your sentence.

**Edit:** In response to the question edit:

> How to generate 1100110?

1100110 = S = 1R = 11R = 110R = 1100R = 11001R = 110011R = 1100110

Hope that helps you understand.

Good Luck!

Comment: The part I don't get is 0R, where does the question state that it is a rule?

Comment: @AndreasJohannessen Could you clarify that question?